# Formatting a strptime value from a string as a date

Tags: python, datetime, strptime, string-conversion

I have the following code which is the beginnings of reading in a text file, turning it into a json object, then grabbing some of the values within it and manipulating the date string read in:

```
    import json
    from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

    my_list = []
    my_list2 = []

    filepath = 'myfile'
    x_contents = open(filepath, "r")
    x_contents = x_contents.read()
    x_contents = json.loads(x_contents.replace("u'", '"').replace("'", '"'))

    for mydate in x_contents:

        for mydate2 in mydate:

            the_match = mydate2[0]
            the_date = mydate2[2]
            the_date = datetime.strptime(the_date,"%A, %b %d %Y")
            print the_date #writes to the log in the correct format

            my_list.append(the_match)
            my_list.append(the_date) #appends the strptime tuple to the list, not the formatted date as it appears with the print statement above

            my_list2.append(my_list)
            my_list = []

for i in my_list2:

    print i
```

Some sample output:

```
2015-08-08 00:00:00
2015-08-08 00:00:00
2015-08-08 00:00:00
2015-08-08 00:00:00
2015-08-08 00:00:00
...
...
...
[958431, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8, 0, 0)]
[958427, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8, 0, 0)]
[958429, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8, 0, 0)]
[958430, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8, 0, 0)]
[958433, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8, 0, 0)]
...
...
...
```

Can anyone tell me the bit I am missing to get the second element of the list into the correct format?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get your question, can you give more details?

Comment: please see comments to question below

Comment: @gdogg371: Try `my_list.append(str(the_date))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `'2015-08-08 00:00:00'` is what you mean by "correct format". If so:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8, 0, 0)
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8, 0, 0)
>>> str(t)
'2015-08-08 00:00:00'
```

An object when printed as an element in a container is printed by calling its `__repr__`, not `__str__`, which is why your `datetime` objects do not appear to be formatted in a list. See this:

```
>>> repr(t)
'datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8, 0, 0)'
>>> [t, str(t)]
[datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 8, 0, 0), '2015-08-08 00:00:00']
```

EDIT:

Now given your list printing code, it's in fact quite easy. Just change it to:

```
for i in my_list2:
    # instead of i, print a list in which every item in i is converted to str(i)
    print [str(item) for item in i]
```

Or equivalently:

```
for i in my_list2:
    # map(str, i) does the same thing as [str(item) for item in i]
    print map(str, i)  # would have to be list(map(str, i)) in python 3
```

It seems that you are not familiar with list comprehension and `map`. Read about them [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: ive edited my question slightly...i am reading in a string from a file that represents a date...im using strptime to convert that into an actual date value. if i print the value i assign that to (the_date) i get a date value in the correct format...if i append 'the_date' to a list though and then print that list i get a strptime tuple of the components of the date, rather than the date, which is not what i want...

Comment: @gdogg371 That's because an object in a container is printed by calling its `__repr__`. If you want to invoke its `__str__` method, you need to do it explicitly with `str()`.

Comment: i dont want it to be a string though, i want it to be a date value as i will be comparing it to a date generated from datetime.today()...

Comment: @gdogg371 You can keep them as `datetime` objects in lists and only convert by `str()` when you print the lists. Maybe if you post your list-printing code (that's not in what you currently posted) then I can help figure how best to do that.

Comment: i have amended the code now so the bit where the list prints is right at the bottom of the code. thanks

Comment: ok, thanks, that worked. could very briefly talk me through what is happening in the printing the list out part of your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(the_date, "%x %X")
```

(or some other format string) to format the datetime the way you want. Look at [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for more guidance.

Comment: this puts it into a string value though rather than a value you would get from a statement such as datetime.today()